# Go net/http routes

Tags: go

I created the routes organized way. But it seems like it's not reaching my `controller` folder. I don't get a response from the controller folder. Can anyone please tell me what error or mistake am making here? Thank you

Heres the main file

https://go.dev/play/p/vSVk_78pcF4

On my browser am hitting the route

`localhost:8000/api/v1//tasks`

and

`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/tasks`

But both routes tells `no page found`

Full Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/sayedulkrm/go-curd-todo/routes"
)

func main() {

    taskRouter := routes.TaskRoutes()

    mainRouter := http.NewServeMux()

    mainRouter.Handle("/api/v1/", taskRouter)

    fmt.Printf("Server running on port 8000")

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", mainRouter)

}

// Routes folder    ===================================

package routes

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/sayedulkrm/go-curd-todo/controllers"
)

func TaskRoutes() *http.ServeMux {

    router := http.NewServeMux()

    fmt.Printf("Heyyy Am getting called From TaskRoutes")

    router.HandleFunc("GET /tasks", controllers.GetAllTasks)

    return router

}


// Controllers Folder ===================================

package controllers

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func GetAllTasks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fmt.Printf("Heyyy Am getting called From Controllers")

    w.Write([]byte(`{"message": "working..."}`))

}
```

I want to make kinda like nested routes.
For example

from frontend, i will hit

```
example.com/api/v1/task
```

I want to break down here

```
main.go

`/api/v1` will be added in front of all routes i will create

so for example for order. it will be

`api/v1/orders`

For users:

`api/v1/users`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mux is also a handler. So basically, you create a mux for your API, let it handle the requests without the prefix and mount that handler to the according prefix in your root handler.

However, since your API mux has no idea about the prefix it is mounted under, you need to strip this prefix:

```golang
// Create a new ServeMux that is responsible for handling your API requests.
api := http.NewServeMux()
api.Handle("/users", userHandler)
api.Handle("/posts", postHandler)

root := http.NewServeMux()
// A mux is also a http.Handler. So, simply use your api mux
// as a handler for the correct path. HOWEVER, since the subrouter does
// have no clue about the /api/v1/ prefix, you need to strip it off.
// So basically, if a request for /api/v1/users comes in, the /api/v1/ part
// is stripped off and the /users part is passed to the api mux.
// Note that you will have to order the paths from most to least specific.
root.Handle("/api/v1/", http.StripPrefix("/api/v1", api))
```

<kbd>**[Run on Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/aVXKkDMl-LF)**</kbd>

Comment: @SayedulKarim Well, I tested it... So it better should. ;)

Comment: I have another question. How can I handle the error kinda like ``` Method Not Allowed``` from the router?

For example, I created a customer JSON error. So if The method is not allowed it will call the JSON function and return it.

In this video he use `httprouter` 
https://youtu.be/2unYC4p4A-U?si=IR177vFaL4nrqKEV&t=1338

Comment: @SayedulKarim As per questions: One per question ;)

Comment: Hahaha okay, then I have to create another question. Btw thank you so much <3